# Need to replicate in PHP an Ruby function that solves a simples captcha

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am  translating some older code from ruby to php, in there there is a piece of code in ruby that solves a captcha image (Example of the captcha image: [Image](http://aplicacoes5.trtsp.jus.br/consultasphp/public/captcha/image.php?id=YToxMDp7czo5OiJjcnlwdFRleHQiO3M6NToiZ8VUXCUiO3M6NToid2lkdGgiO3M6MzoiMTgwIjtzOjY6ImhlaWdodCI7czoyOiI4MCI7czoxMjoiaW1hZ2VCZ0NvbG9yIjtzOjc6IiNmZmZmY2MiO3M6OToidGV4dENvbG9yIjtzOjc6IiM3MDcwNzAiO3M6MTA6InN0YXJ0SW1hZ2UiO047czoxMzoiZG90Tm9pc2VMZXZlbCI7aTo1MDtzOjE0OiJsaW5lTm9pc2VMZXZlbCI7aTo1O3M6NDoiZm9udCI7czo1ODoiL3ZvbDEvd3d3L2h0bWwvY29uc3VsdGFzcGhwL2FwcGxpY2F0aW9uLy4uL2ZvbnRzL2FyaWFsLnR0ZiI7czo4OiJmb250U2l6ZSI7czoyOiIzNiI7fQ==))

```
  def exterminator_captchas(page)
    captcha = PHP.unserialize(Base64.decode64(page.images[14].to_s.sub(/.*?id=/, '')))
    [captcha['cryptText'].bytes, [0x51, 0xac, 0x6d, 0x33, 0x12]].transpose.map {|pair| pair[0]^pair[1]}.pack('C*')
```

The problem is that i don't have the slightest idea on how to start solving this since i don't know Ruby very well. Some help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, here is how i did it. Thanks for D Lowther for directing me to the right functions.

```
preg_match_all('/(?:.*?)id=(.*?)\Z/isu',$captchaUrlAdd, $output);
    $target = $output[1][0];
    $target = base64_decode($target);
    $target = unserialize($target);
    $target = $target['cryptText'];
    $target = unpack('C*', $target);
    $target = array_values($target);

    $mappingArray = [hexdec('0x51'), hexdec('0xac'), hexdec('0x6d'), hexdec('0x33'), hexdec('0x12')];

    $targetByteArray = array();
    foreach ([$target, $mappingArray] as $row => $columns) {
        foreach ($columns as $row2 => $column2) {
            $targetByteArray[$row2][$row] = $column2;
        }
    }
    $targetEndArray = array();
    foreach ($targetByteArray as $arr) {
        $targetEndArray[] = $arr[0] ^ $arr[1];
    }

    $stringFinal = '';
    foreach ($targetEndArray as $end) {
        $stringFinal .=pack('C*', $end);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at it, I've left some work for you to do research-wise but this should at least get you on the track :).

```
function exterminator_captchas($page)
{
  $captcha = unserialize(
    base64_decode(
      preg_replace('/.*?id=/', '', (string)$page['images'][14])
    )
  );

  // This next bit is a bit of pseudo-code I think you'd need to 
  // play with unpack to get the bytestreams.
  $map = [
    /*some unpacking method*/($captcha),
    [0x51, 0xac, 0x6d, 0x33, 0x12],
  ];
  // http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose
  // would need to look for the right array manipulating method to match.
  $transpose = /* some method */($map);

  return pack('C*', array_map(
    function(pair) {
      return ($pair[0]^$pair[1]);
    }, 
    $transpose
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for. After looking a bit i found out it was converting the id argument of the image, not the image.

Again thanks for the functions, since i'm not very familiar with ruby